# Как создать массив, картинки которого привязаны к одному ImageView?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, в своем приложении-викторине я храню вопросы и ответы в двух текстовых файлах. Можно ли создать массив с картинками (по одной на вопрос), чтобы он был привязан к одному ImageView?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Что значит "массив картинок, привязанных к ImageView"?

Comment: Один ImageView в разметке и в коде просто меняйте у него содержимое

Comment: картинки из массива должен отображать один ImageView в xml файле

Comment: @A.Schtolc, вы хотите переодически менять картинку в ImageVeiw или отобразить сразу все в одном ImageView? Ваш вопрос всё ещё не понятен.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хотелось, чтобы в ImageView переодически менялась картинка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос состоит из нескольких частей:

1. Как запустить некий код с определённой периодичностью?
2. Как назначить картинку в ImageView из массива картинок.

Первое - делать можно очень по разному. Например, через Timer и TimerTask как-то так:

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;

timer = new Timer();
timerTask = new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //код здесь выполнится раз в 5000мс
                //именно тут можно поменять картинку в ImageView (см. далее ответ)
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
```

Второе - сначала создаём массив с, например, `int`-овыми значениями ID-шников картинок из класса R, т.е. тех, что лежат в папке `res/drawable`

```
int[] imgsArray = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.another_img, R.drawable.another_img_1};
//например генерируем случайное число и устанавливаем в ImageView картинку, извелекая её ID из массива по случайному индексу
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.nextInt(imgsArray.lenght);
int randomImgId = imgsArray[index];
ImageView iv = ...;
iv.setImageResource(randomImgId);
```

Теперь, собственно, поместив второй кусок кода вместо комментария в первом вы получите случайную картинку из массива, коя будет меняться раз в 5с